# JPARepository findAllById performance issue with table >200 columns

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Scenario:

Application: Springboot,

Database: MSSQL

Table Name: Accounts

Number of columns : 255

No of Rows: 5,00,000

Primary key(composite): ApplicationNumber,AccountNumber

Problem:

When we use JPARepository.findAllById(AccountsPk pk) to query the table passing in EmbeddedId it is taking more than 1 minute.

1. I have enabled show-sql=true and executed generated sql directly in SQLServerManagementStudio and can get the result in 1 second.
2. Using EntityManager, i can obtain result in <3 seconds.

Time elapsed : <3sec
Sample code:

```
EntityManager em;
....
...
Query q= em.createQuery(select a from Accounts where a where a.id.accountNumber='xxx' and a.id.applicationNumber='YYYY') ;

List<Accounts> accounts = q.getResultList();
em.close;
```

Is there any known limitation in JpaRepository for performance degradation when the table has more number of columns/data compared to using entitymanager?

Comment: *Is there any known limitation in JpaRepository for performance degradation when the table has more number of columns/data compared to using entitymanager?* Spring Data's JPA repositories are simply an abstraction over the Entity manager so no. Enable SQL logging and see if the the query executed matches the one youy have manually defined.

Comment: Alan is right. And try yo use paginaiton to get records and avoid your application to future NotEnoghMemory errors.

Comment: I have tried with SQL logging. The query generated by hibernate for JpaRepository case and EntityManger case are same

Comment: @JaumeMoróniTarrasa The query is expected to return max 1 row(querying by PK)